# OverWrite an existing list in CSV files Python

Tags: python, list, csv

I have a csv files with player attributes:

```
['Peter Regin', '2', 'DAN', 'N', '1987', '6', '6', '199', '74', '2', '608000', '', '77', '52', '74', '72', '58', '72', '71', '72', '70', '72', '74', '68', '74', '41', '40', '51']
['Andrej Sekera', '8', 'SVK', 'N', '1987', '6', '6', '198', '72', '3', '1323000', '', '65', '39', '89', '78', '75', '70', '72', '56', '53', '56', '57', '72', '57', '59', '70', '51']
```

For example, I want to check if a player is a CENTER ('2' in position 1 in my list) and after I want to modify the 12 element (which is '77' for Peter Regin)

How can I do that using the CSV module ?

```
import csv


class ManipulationFichier:


    def __init__(self, fichier):
        self.fichier = fichier

    def read(self):

        with open(self.fichier) as f:
            reader = csv.reader(f)

            for row  in reader:
                print(row)


    def write(self):

        with open(self.fichier) as f:
            writer = csv.writer(f)

            for row in f:
                if row[1] == 2: 
                    writer.writerows(row[1] for row in f)
```

Which do nothing important..

Thanks,

Comment: Can you show us the code you have so far?

Answer (score 2):

In general, CSV files cannot be reliably modified in-place.

Read the entire file into memory (usually a list of lists, as in your example), modify the data, then write the entire file back.

Unless your file is really huge, and you do this really often, the performance hit will be negligible.

Comment: What is the most effective way.

So I should use the mmap module ?
Or write in a list ? using the reader and append ?

Comment: Forget efficiency until you attain correct functioning. Do the simplest thing possible. I bet the bottlenecks of your program are going to be elsewhere :)